# How does a C++ object access its member functions?

Tags: c++

How does a C++ object know where it's member function definitions are present? I am quite confused as the Object itself does not contain the function pointers. 
`sizeof` on the Object proves this.
So how is the object to function mapping done by the Runtime environment? where is a class's member function-pointer table maintained?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're calling non-virtual functions, there's no need for a function-pointer table; the compiler can resolve the function addresses at compile-time.  So:

```
A a;
a.func();
```

translates to something along the lines of:

```
A a;
A_func(&a);
```

Calling a virtual function through a base-class pointer typically uses a [vtable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VTBL).  So:

```
A *p_a = new B();
p_a->func();
```

translates to something along the lines of:

```
A *p_a = new B();
p_a->p_vtbl->func(p_a);
```

where `p_vtbl` is a compiler-implemented pointer to the vtable specific to the actual class of `*p_a`.

Comment: You probably mean compile-time, not run-time.

Comment: @kotlinski He meant the compiler's run-time :)

Comment: You probably mean link-time, not compile-time.

Comment: @Hans:  The compiler picks out which functions to call, and what Oli described was exactly that.  The linker just finds and links the functions.

Answer (score 1):

There are generally two ways that an object and its member functions are associated:

- For a non-virtual function, the compiler determines the appropriate function at compile time. Non-static member functions are usually passed a hidden parameter that contains the `this` pointer, which takes care of the association of the object and the class member function.
- For virtual functions, most compilers tend to use a lookup table that is usually referenced via the object's `this` pointer or a similar mechanism. This table, normally called the vtable, contains the function pointer for the virtual functions only.

As C++ is not a dynamic language, the compiler can do most of the object/function/symbol resolution at compile time with the exception of some virtual functions. In some cases, it's even possible for the compiler to determine exactly which instance of a virtual function gets called and skip the resolution via the vtable.

Answer (score 0):

Member functions are not part of the object - they are defined statically, in one place, just like any other function. There is no magic look-up needed.

Virtual functions are different, but I don't think your question is about that...

Answer (score 0):

For non-virtual functions there is one (global, per-class) function table which all instances use.  Since it's the same for all of them - deterministic at compile-time - you would not want it duplicated in each instance.

For virtual functions, resolution is done at runtime and the object will contain a function table for them.  Try that and look at your object again.